# How to change bucket name in MongoDB GridFS?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, mongo-java

I am using Mongo-Java-Driver 3.0.

How can i change bucket name from `fs` to `new_name` in MongoDB GridFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `bucket` argument to the constructor, as documented in the [Java GridFS API](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFS.html).

GridFS(db, "new_name")

Is this not working for you? If not, what happens? What's the error?